# Confusing Volumetrics

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, emission

[image]I have a simple glass exture applied to this bulb and a circle inside with an emission texture on it w/ the strength about 30. How do I get this emission texture to fill the bulb?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my node setup for a light bulb, I hope it helps. It worked well for my scene.[image]
You can use this for the bulb only, if you want, or you can keep the emmission sphere, and use the glass settings.